# How to break a list comprised of several lists into just one list?

Tags: python, list

I am coding in Python.

I am able to write code that returns a list of dates, which I want. Now, for every date, I would like to find the cell value for that date. In order to do that I wrote a for loop:

```
element = []
for item in result:
    cell_list = worksheet2.findall(item)
    element.append(cell_list)
```

When I print element, the code returns the following response:

```
[[<Cell R6C3 '2/18/2015'>, <Cell R11C3 '2/18/2015'>], [<Cell R16C3 
'2/19/2015'>, <Cell R21C3 '2/19/2015'>, <Cell R26C3 '2/19/2015'>, <Cell R31C3 
'2/19/2015'>, <Cell R36C3 '2/19/2015'>, <Cell R41C3 '2/19/2015'>], [<Cell 
R46C3 '3/10/2015'>, <Cell R51C3 '3/10/2015'>, <Cell R56C3 '3/10/2015'>], 
[<Cell R61C3 '3/17/2015'>, <Cell R66C3 '3/17/2015'>, <Cell R71C3 '3/17/2015'>, 
<Cell R76C3 '3/17/2015'>, <Cell R81C3 '3/17/2015'>, <Cell R86C3 '3/17/2015'>, 
<Cell R91C3 '3/17/2015'>, <Cell R96C3 '3/17/2015'>], [<Cell R101C3 
'3/18/2015'>, <Cell R106C3 '3/18/2015'>, <Cell R111C3 '3/18/2015'>, <Cell 
R116C3 '3/18/2015'>, <Cell R121C3 '3/18/2015'>, <Cell R126C3 '3/18/2015'>, 
<Cell R131C3 '3/18/2015'>]]
```

How do I get the code to not put several lists into one list? I just want one big list with all of those cells instead of several list in one list.

Answer (score 1):

Fast reply

```
element.extend(cell_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.extend()` works, but another possibility is the `+=` operator:

```
element += cell_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) function to chain your lists. It returns iterator, so to convert it to list just pass it as constructor argument.

```
from itertools import chain

lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
elements = list(chain(*lists))

print(elements)
```

Above code prints `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.